# Require element based on position and attribute value

Tags: xml, xsd, attributes, element, xsd-1.0

I have the following XSD (part of the XSD)

```
            <xs:element name="sourceValue" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:simpleContent>
                        <xs:extension base="xs:normalizedString">
                            <xs:attribute name="label" type="xs:normalizedString" 
                                          use="required"/>  
                        </xs:extension>
                    </xs:simpleContent>
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
```

In my XML I have:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Record xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="assertion.xsd">
  <SSN>33333332</SSN>
  <sourceValue label="nrA">33333333</sourceValue>
  <sourceValue label="nrB">111111111</sourceValue>
  <Data>
    <Patient>
      <DateOfBirth>03-04-2000</DateOfBirth>
      <Sexe>M</Sexe>
      <Name>Patient A</Name>
    </Patient>
  </Data>
</Record>
```

I want to change my XSD in such a way that when sourceValue with label="nrA" is mandatory, but with label="nrB" is optional. But I cannot figure out how to do this.

Comment: Can you give a sample of a valid and a sample of an invalid document? Also which version of the schema language do you want to use? In the current version 1.1 you can use assertions with XPath which gives you much more expressiveness than 1.0 has.

Comment: Also, *what* is optional or mandatory based upon the value of `label`?  It sounds like you're saying that the requiredness of the `sourceValue` element itself should depend upon the value of one of its attributes, but that would not make sense.

Comment: Hi @Martin Honnen, version is 1.0.

Comment: @kjhughes, you are correct. Both labels are present, but I want to have the first sourceValue with label="nrA" to be mandatory. the complete xml sample looks like 'code' <Record >
<SSN>33333332</SSN>
<sourceValue label="nrA">33333333</sourceValue>
<sourceValue label="nrB">111111111</sourceValue>
<Data>
<Patient>
  <DateOfBirth>03-04-2000</DateOfBirth>
  <Sexe>M</Sexe>
  <Name>Patient A</Name>
</Patient>
</Data>
</Record>
'code

Comment: @Stephan: Use xsd-1.0 tag when you cannot use xsd-1.1, and add XML to question, not in comments.  I've done both for you this time.  You cannot specify such constraints in XSD 1.0; see [my answer for further details](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31371411/290085).

Answer (score 2):

### XSD 1.0

Not possible.  Instead, you should use different element names for the two cases.

### XSD 1.1

Different element names are still recommended, but if you must follow your current approach, you can use assertions:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  xmlns:vc="http://www.w3.org/2007/XMLSchema-versioning" vc:minVersion="1.1">

  <xs:element name="Record">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="SSN" type="xs:string"/>
        <xs:element ref="sourceValue"/>
        <xs:element ref="sourceValue" minOccurs="0"/>
        <xs:element name="Data">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="Patient">
                <xs:complexType>
                  <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="DateOfBirth" type="xs:string"/>
                    <xs:element name="Sexe" type="xs:string"/>
                    <xs:element name="Name" type="xs:string"/>
                  </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
              </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
      <xs:assert test="sourceValue[1]/@label = 'nrA'"/>
      <xs:assert test="not(sourceValue[2]) or sourceValue[2]/@label = 'nrA'"/>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>

  <xs:element name="sourceValue">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:simpleContent>
        <xs:extension base="xs:string">
          <xs:attribute name="label" type="xs:string"/>
        </xs:extension>
      </xs:simpleContent>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Comment: Thanks you, unfortunately I'm restricted to this xml as is. So in my case it is just not possible. I did try using different element-names, but than the xml file was not process correctly in the application we are using. Otherwise that would be the best option indeed, to use different element-names.